# How to check which timezone in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

Is there a way to check which time zone I'm currently in on Linux?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Usually, the `TZ` environment variable will tell you something useful. However, it is best to use functions such as `mktime()` and `localtime()` to convert between `time_t` and a local timezone representation. That is, *don't try to do the conversion yourself*.

Comment: is there any Command that tells about timezone the user is in?

Comment: Sure, `date` will tell you.

Comment: i have two instance of server , if i give "date" command in both server it shows different time. time zone for both server is IST, time of one server: Mon Jul 11 10:39:31 IST 2011 and other server Mon Jul 11 10:35:31 IST 2011 .. there is a difference of 4 minutes

Comment: Well that's an entirely different problem than "What timezone am I in?". I suggest you install NTP on your servers.

Comment: On Precise Pangolin `echo $TZ` returns nothing for me.

Comment: @IainElder: That just means that processes without a specific `TZ` set will use the system default (whatever that is). Setting `TZ` can be used to override the system default on a per-process basis.

Comment: @GregHewgill your answer is not helpful at first view. Consider editing your answer please. See the most voted answer below. I will downvote your answer for now. Also there is no TZ env on default on my machines.

Comment: unfortunately "date" at least in it's default output only displays an ambiguious three letter abreviation, not the actual timezone selected.

Answer (score 292):

If you mean from the console, just type:

```
date +%Z
```

Comment: And to set the timezone from the command line in Ubuntu, the following link provides the trivial, 1-line command to do so: http://askubuntu.com/a/524362/182454

Comment: This gives `+07` for me. To get `Region/City` on a Debian / Arch based Linux, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1334239/365890).

Comment: Use `date +%z` for `+hhmm` numeric time zone (e.g., `-0400`).

Answer (score 74):

If you want the numeric timezone:

### `date +'%:z %Z'`

Sample output:

```
-05:00 EST
```

Comment: On OS X this outputs `:z EST`

Comment: This if for [tag:linux].

Comment: More precisely, this applies to GNU `date`. The BusyBox version prints something non-sensical, "%:z CEST" in my case.

Comment: However, date +%z works fine on OS X. I suggest you modify the answer.

Comment: Hi, @NeilMayhew Thanks! Humm... but the question has the tags `linux` `ubuntu-10.04 `

Comment: True, but %z works just as well for this purpose. It prints -0500 instead of -05:00. I think it's best to avoid Linux-only (or, in this case, GNU-only) things just for the sake of finesse.

Comment: @NeilMayhew The question is titled *"How to check which timezone in **Linux**?"*, why would anyone (who reads it or comes into this seeking for help) care for an OSX or an OS-agnostic answer?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ it's the first result for "get timezone unix"

Comment: I realize this thread is a linux question/answer, but it is clear that many Google searches by OSX users are coming to this thread, so here is an OSX 10.6.8 command line example (without the colon):  `date +'%z %Z' `

Comment: @lawlist That's great! I will add it to my answer.

Comment: I am writing a software where I don't trust users. I wanted to get the system timezone. But this will let me change my timezone via the `TZ` environment variable. For example `TZ=Arctic/Longyearbyen date +%:z` shows `+01:00` but not `+05:30` where I am currently in...

Answer (score 30):

I wanted to find the timezone in "US/Eastern" or "Europe/London" form instead. You can find this in:

- /etc/timezone (present on Ubuntu and Red Hat? but not e.g. Amazon Linux)
- (on Red Hat style systems) as `ZONE="US/Eastern"` in /etc/sysconfig/clock
- or you can try and match /etc/localtime to one of the files under /usr/share/zoneinfo; annoyingly this doesn't seem to be a symlink, but you can e.g.

  > cd /usr/share/zoneinfo
  >   find * -type f -exec sh -c "diff -q /etc/localtime '{}' > /dev/null && echo {}" \;

  to find matching files - there's probably better ways to do that, but that works. There will be multiple matches.

Comment: `find /usr/share/zoneinfo/ -type f| xargs md5sum | grep $(md5sum /etc/localtime  | cut -d' ' -f1)`

Answer (score 20):

Sometimes you may be looking for the canonical timezone rather than the short form as produced by `date %Z` e.g. `US/Eastern`. On systems with `timedatectl` e.g. Fedora, `timedatectl` outputs lots of useful information, including the current zone:

```
# timedatectl
      Local time: Tue 2016-09-13 17:10:26 EDT
  Universal time: Tue 2016-09-13 21:10:26 UTC
        RTC time: Tue 2016-09-13 21:10:26
       Time zone: US/Eastern (EDT, -0400)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Unfortunately, `timedatectl` takes `set-timezone` as a command, but has no corresponding `get-timezone`. Parse it as follows:

```
# timedatectl status | grep "zone" | sed -e 's/^[ ]*Time zone: \(.*\) (.*)$/\1/g'`
US/Eastern
```

For systemd >= 241, see [@BurninateSE's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1589527/78675) (TLDR: `timedatectl show --va -p Timezone`).

Answer (score 16):

For ubuntu try this :

```
$ cat /etc/timezone
```

Sample output :

```
Asia/Kolkata
```

For other distro Reference : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110522/timezone-setting-in-linux

Comment: Sometimes [`timedatectl set-timezone` doesn't update `/etc/timezone`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/451709/143394). See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1334239/365890) for a solution based on `/etc/localtime`.

Answer (score 8):

For the time zone, you can use geolocation:

```
$ curl https://ipapi.co/timezone
America/Chicago
```

Or:

```
$ curl http://ip-api.com/line?fields=timezone
America/Chicago
```

http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/time#Time_zone

Comment: Just want to point out that although this will _likely_ return the correct timezone the server is located at it does not necessarily return the timezone the server is configured for.

Answer (score 6):

All of the following solutions will give you an [IANA compatible Olson timezone ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olson%20database#Names_of_time_zones) (e.g. `America/Los_Angeles`). However, some may return extra whitespace at the beginning and/or end - trim if required.

### Using the environment

The environment variable `TZ` (if set) [specifies the timezone](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html). Checking this first is essential.

```
$ echo $TZ
```

I can personally confirm that this works on ALL of my modern Linux hosts.

### Using `Systemd` version >= 241

This is the preferred method for all those who believe Systemd shall rule the world.

```
$ timedatectl show --va -p Timezone
```

If you get an error similar to `timedatectl: invalid option -- 'p'` that means your Systemd isn't ready to rule the world. Instead...

### Using `Systemd` and `sed`

Improvement upon [Raman's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1124045/905389), but without the useless use of grep. This solution is optimal on systems utilizing older versions of Systemd.

```
$ timedatectl | sed -n 's/^\s*Time zone: \(.*\) (.*/\1/p'
```

### Using `/etc/timezone`

This is a simple readable file, but doesn't seem to be available on as many distros anymore. IIRC, this is something those Debian devs came up with a while ago that fell out of favour.

```
$ cat /etc/timezone
```

### Using GNU `realpath` because `/etc/localtime` is a symlink

This solution is optimal if you know that `/etc/localtime` is a symlink, which is something that both a lot of older software and guides accomplish and even modern SystemD promises; and you also have GNU realpath available, which should also be available on every GNU OS distro.

```
$ realpath --relative-to /usr/share/zoneinfo /etc/localtime
```

### D'oh! `/etc/localtime` **isn't** a symlink; using `find`, `sed`, `md5sum`

If you find yourself with a non-symlink `/etc/localtime` (the command shown above will either error or provide a path that starts with `../`), you can try to locate its md5 match in your local timezone database. This may return multiple matches as there are quite a few aliases in the Olson database.

```
$ find /usr/share/zoneinfo -type f -exec md5sum {} + |\
  sed /$(printf $(md5sum /etc/localtime))/'!d;s/.\{54\}//;/^posix/d'
```

If you'd only like a single timezone ID returned (whichever one is returned first by the system's [readdir()](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/unix/ReaddirOrder)), you can use sed's `q` command to quit after the first match. This is much more performant than starting up `head` for instance. However, this causes `find` to break the pipe with `md5sum` early, causing an error to print to fd 2. You may ignore this error by piping it to /dev/null as the following complete command demonstrates:

```
$ find /usr/share/zoneinfo -type f -exec md5sum {} + 2> /dev/null |\
  sed /$(printf $(md5sum /etc/localtime))/'!d;s/.\{54\}//;/^posix/d;q'
```

### Using `curl` and geolocation

If for some reason you don't want or don't trust the host's configuration (or just hate their guts) but you're certain that it can connect to the wider world web, there are several gratis online services that will geolocate you (whilst they last). Below are some examples:

```
$ curl -Lsf https://ipapi.co/timezone # Defunct?

$ curl -Lsf http://ip-api.com/line?fields=timezone

$ curl -Lsf https://ipwhois.app/line/?objects=timezone

$ curl -Lsf http://api.ipgeolocation.io/timezone -e ';auto' | jq -r .timezone
```

First two services shamelessly stolen from [Steven Penny's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1335722/905389). Additionally I implore the SE community to please keep this list up to date with working links thanks!

CW: politics:

> Finally, I beg of you to please don't use this method to bind your users and steal their agency - only use this method if they ask you to do so!
>
> Also note that while these services are gratis, please consider visiting their respective web sites to learn about and accept their terms and conditions before using.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ strings /etc/localtime | tail -n 1
MST7MDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0
```

So I'm on Mountain Time.
Although advices above on using environment variable or just date command output sometimes work better, depending how you want to use that.

Answer (score 3):

I have linux mint Cinnamon.
`timedatectl` gave the information I needed:

```
                  Local time: Mon 2020-06-29 11:04:27 PDT
              Universal time: Mon 2020-06-29 18:04:27 UTC
                    RTC time: Mon 2020-06-29 18:04:27
                   Time zone: America/Vancouver (PDT, -0700)
   System clock synchronized: yes
```

systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
RTC in local TZ: no

Answer (score 2):

- /etc/sysconfig/clock sets whether the hardware clock is stored as UTC or local time.
- Symlink /etc/localtime to /usr/share/zoneinfo/... to set your timezone.
- Type `/sbin/hwclock --systohc [--utc]` to set the hardware clock.

The Linux kernel always stores and calculates time as the number of seconds since midnight of the 1st of January 1970 UTC regardless of whether your hardware clock is stored as UTC or not. Conversions to your local time are done at run-time. One neat thing about this is that if someone is using your computer from a different timezone, they can set the TZ environment variable and all dates and times will appear correct for their timezone.

If the number of seconds since the 1st of January 1970 UTC is stored as an signed 32-bit integer (as it is on your Linux/Intel system), your clock will stop working sometime on the year 2038. Linux has no inherent Y2K problem, but it does have a year 2038 problem. Hopefully we'll all be running Linux on 64-bit systems by then. 64-bit integers will keep our clocks running quite well until aproximately the year 292271-million.

Answer (score 2):

Using TZ or date IS NOT RELIABLE because it tells you the USER's timezone, not the default system timezone.

The default system timezone is stored in /etc/timezone (which is often a symbolic link to the timezone data file specific to the timezone).  If you do not have an /etc/timezone, look at /etc/localtime.  Generally that is the "server's" timezone.  /etc/localtime is often a symlink to a timezone file in /usr/share/zoneinfo.  That path to the correct timezone file will often give you geography information as well.

Newer linux have "timedatectl" which gives you tons of info when the command is run.

(as a side-node, if you have an ancient system that still uses the OLD hard-coded timezones, you can probably copy a modern timezone file onto it and it will work.  I have had to do this many times to resolve changing timezones on older equipment).

Answer (score 2):

A couple of solutions:

```
date +"%Z %z"
timedatectl | grep "Time zone"
cat /etc/timezone
```

gave me (respectively):

```
UTC +0000
Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
Etc/UTC
```

My computer is on UTC.

Answer (score 2):

Systemd added more options, so I don't have to grep, sed or awk a lot:

```bsh
$ timedatectl show -p Timezone --value
Europe/Berlin
```

This works on Debian Buster (systemd 241) but not on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic (systemd 237). So I use this in scripts now to keep it simple and clean:

```bsh
$ timedatectl show -p Timezone --value || cat "/etc/timezone"
Europe/Berlin
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes [`timedatectl set-timezone` doesn't update `/etc/timezone`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/451709/143394), so it's best to get the tiemzone from the name of the file that the symlink `/etc/timezone` points to:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

if filename=$(readlink /etc/localtime); then
    # /etc/localtime is a symlink as expected
    timezone=${filename#*zoneinfo/}
    if [[ $timezone = "$filename" || ! $timezone =~ ^[^/]+/[^/]+$ ]]; then
        # not pointing to expected location or not Region/City
        >&2 echo "$filename points to an unexpected location"
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "$timezone"
else  # compare files by contents
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521114/getting-the-canonical-time-zone-name-in-shell-script#comment88637393_12523283
    find /usr/share/zoneinfo -type f ! -regex ".*/Etc/.*" -exec \
        cmp -s {} /etc/localtime \; -print | sed -e 's@.*/zoneinfo/@@' | head -n1
fi
```

References: in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451925/143394).

Answer (score 1):

You can show date and the timezone concurrently:

```
date +'%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M:%S [%:z  %Z]'
```